# HTML Bullet points in rows not vertical

Tags: html

How do you make it so bullet points are like this(HTML):

- BP1       BP2      BP3       BP4

and not this

- e.g
- e.g

I've tried different things and nothing is working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `display: inline`?

Comment: `<ul><li>BP1 BP2 BP3 BP4</li></ul>` ??

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>BP1</li>
  <li>BP2</li>
  <li>BP3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li:first-child::before {
  content: "•";
  margin-right: .5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, if I wanted to change that to columns is that possible too? How would that be done?

Comment: In columns but only the first element has the bullet-point? Set the li to `display: block` and `margin-left: 1em` (maybe a different value applies to match the spacing of the first list-item with the bullet) and the li:first-child to margin-left: 0. At least that would work if I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I assume this is what you are looking for?

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Bp1</li>
  <li>Bp2</li>
  <li>Bp3</li>
  <li>Bp4</li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS should look something like this:

```
ul li{
  display:inline;
}

li::before {
 content: '\25cf\a0';
}
```

Look at this fiddle to see the result:  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2584urt/)

Comment: That's not correct. As you did not reset the list-style on the ul, you'd still have bullets in front of every list-item. On top you now added another set of bullets in front of each list-item with the ::before pseudo-element.